# Is there a module that saves the node while you are creating it?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a blog, I write blogposts everyday. Today I was creating a blog post, I was almost finished, but for some reason my computer turned off. I lost all that I had in my article I have to write it again.

Is there a module or something that saves the node while you are creating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need the [Autosave](https://www.drupal.org/project/autosave) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> The Autosave module automatically saves a snapshot of your content type form using AJAX. If the user's browser or machine dies while editing a node; the edits will be presented to the user the next time they return to the node. The user may toggle back and forth between the last saved version and the version with the edits that were lost and select which of these they would like to continue with.
>
> How often a form is autosaved as well as which content types to enable autosave for are admin configurable.